# Linq select subgroup

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following in my db table:

```
- MailingId | GroupName | ServiceId
-   1       |  group1   |   3
-   2       |  group1   |   5
-   3       |  group1   |   8
-   4       |  group2   |   null
-   5       |  group3   |   null
...
```

In my view i have 2 groups of checkboxes:

- 1) (services) with id's 3,5,8 (serviceId).
- 2) and a list of checkboxes for mailing groups (group1, group2, group3)

I need to select the following using LINQ:

Select rows that I have selected in ServiceId checkbox list PLUS any other. For example if I check off ServiceId's (3 and 5) and group "Group3" then my output would be rows MailingId: 1, 3 and 5. HOWEVER, if I select ANY service from (first group of checkboxes) AND DO NOT select "Group1" from mailing group checkboxes then rows with Group1 SHOULD NOT be in the output.

I'm using EF4. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 arrays would be the selections that are posted from your view

```
int[] selectedservices = {3,5};
string[] selectedgroups = {"group3"};

using (Model model = new Model())
{
    bool b = selectedservices.Contains(1);

            var mailinglists = from m in model.MalingSet
                               where selectedgroups.Contains(m.GroupName)
                               && ((m.ServiceId.HasValue && selectedservices.Contains(m.ServiceId.Value)) || m.ServiceId.HasValue == false)
                               select m.MailingId;
}
```

Comment: this selects all mailing groups even though i have not checked group1. It should ONLY do a match on serviceId IF group1 is selected from the mailing groups list of checkboxes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
var mailingGroup =
    from m in Mailings
    where m.ServiceId != null // or whatever other condition
    group m by m.GroupName into g
    select new
    {
        groupName = g.Key,
        mailings = g
    };
```

Comment: nope. this only selects rows with serviceId. I need it to select any rows with service id (if any were checked) PLUS rows that do not have service Id that have been checked in 'mailing group' checkbox group.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Where clause no?

```
var a = new {m = 1, g = "group1", sid = 3};
var b = new {m = 2, g = "group1", sid = 5};
var c = new {m = 3, g = "group1", sid = 8};
var d = new {m = 4, g = "group2", sid = 0};
var e = new {m = 5, g = "group3", sid = 0};

var l = new List<dynamic>{a,b,c,d,e};

l.Where(it => ( new ArrayList{3, 5}).Contains(it.sid) 
               || (new ArrayList{1, 5}).Contains(it.m)).Dump();
```

http://www.linqpad.net/